# Xpath: First letter/string immediately following element

Tags: xml, string, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML possibilities:

```
<metamark/><anything>. <anything2>bla</anything2>.</anything>
<metamark/>.<anything> <anything2>bla</anything2>.</anything>
<metamark/><anything><anything2>bla</anything2>.</anything>
```

I want to get the first "." So I tried:

```
starts-with(metamark[not(descendant::text())]/following-sibling::text()[1],'.')
```

Works fine for line 2 above but I miss line 1. So i did:

```
starts-with(metamark[not(descendant::text())]/following-sibling::text()[1],'.') or starts-with(metamark[not(descendant::text())]/following-sibling::*[1]/text()[1],'.')
```

which now works for all lines above. However line 3 should not be true, because I only want "." that are either immediately following the empty `<metamark/>` or the first string of the immediately following sibling, BUT not if there is text in any descendant element of that sibling before the "."

So in plain words: the first text (as in nearest to the actual closing ">" after an element. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: *"The first text node that follows any `<metamark>` as long as it starts with `'.'`"*

```
//metamark[not(descendant::text())]/following::text()[1][starts-with(., '.')]
```

In

```
<r>
  <metamark/><anything>. yes1<anything2>bla</anything2>. no1</anything>
  <metamark/>. yes2<anything> <anything2>bla</anything2>. no2</anything>
  <metamark/><anything><anything2>bla</anything2>. no3</anything>
</r>
```

this retrieves

```
'. yes1'
'. yes2'
```

The `following::` axis ignores nesting, which is useful for this task.